# PHP Unable to read second result set from mysqli statement

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I'm trying to use PHP to read two result sets from a stored procedure.  The first result set is fine, but although the second appears to exist, I'm unable to coerce php into handling it.  Instead, when trying to bind, it fails with the old chestnut

> "PHP Warning:  `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`(): Number of bind variables
>   doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement".

```
public function GetSession($sessionId) {
        $conn = mysqli_connect(DbConstants::$servername, DbConstants::$username, DbConstants::$password, DbConstants::$dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $call = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'CALL Sp_Session_GetById(?)');
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($call, 'i', $sessionId);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($call);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result(
            $call,
            $id,
            $startTime,
            $duration,
            $description,
            $instructorId,
            $aircraftId,
            $display,
            $bookable,
            $cancelled
        );

        mysqli_stmt_fetch($call);
        $session = new Session($id, $startTime, $duration, $description, $instructorId, $aircraftId, $display, $bookable, $cancelled, []);

        if(mysqli_stmt_more_results($call)) { /* This is true */
            mysqli_stmt_next_result($call);
            /* This is where it goes wrong */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result(
                $call,
                $sessionTypeId,
                $spaces,
                $enabled
            );
        }
}
```

If I execute the stored procedure in mysql workbench, the I get two tabs of results looking like this:

```
# id, startTime, duration, description, instructor_id, aircraft_id, display, bookable, cancelled
'38', '2018-05-19 09:00:00', '180', NULL, '18', '2', '1', '1', '0'

# sessiontype_id, spaces, enabled
'1', '3', '1'
'2', '3', '1'
```

The stored procedure was created as follows:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_Session_GetById (IN
    _id int
)
BEGIN
SELECT 
    s.id,
    s.startTime,
    s.duration,
    s.description,
    s.instructor_id,
    s.aircraft_id,
    s.display,
    s.bookable,
    s.cancelled
FROM session s
WHERE s.id = _id
AND s.cancelled = false
AND s.display = true;

SELECT sst.sessiontype_id, sst.spaces, sst.enabled
FROM session_sessiontype as sst
WHERE sst.session_id = _id;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_next_result()` is only used with `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: I don't think `mysqli` can deal with calling a procedure that returns multiple result sets. It only knows about multiple result sets when you use `mysqli_multi_query`.

Comment: You may want to show also called procedure and the table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got multiple result sets working using Barmar's suggestion of using mysqli_multi_query(), which I'll post below.  However, it does not use mysqli_stmt_next_result(), so if someone does provide a working solution using mysqli_stmt_next_result() I'll mark theirs as the accepted solution.

```
        public function GetSession($sessionId) {
        $conn = mysqli_connect(DbConstants::$servername, DbConstants::$username, DbConstants::$password, DbConstants::$dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $query = 'CALL Sp_Session_GetById(' . $sessionId . ');';
        mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query);

        $sessionResult = mysqli_store_result($conn);
        $sessionRow = mysqli_fetch_row($sessionResult);

        $session = new Session(
            $sessionRow[0],
            $sessionRow[1],
            $sessionRow[2],
            $sessionRow[3],
            $sessionRow[4],
            $sessionRow[5],
            $sessionRow[6],
            $sessionRow[7],
            $sessionRow[8],
            []);

        mysqli_free_result($sessionResult);

        mysqli_next_result($conn);

        $sessionTypeResult = mysqli_store_result($conn);
        while($sessionTypeRow = mysqli_fetch_row($sessionTypeResult)) {
            array_push($session->sessionTypesForSession, $sessionTypeRow[0]);
        }

        $conn->close();

        return $session;

    }
```